# Combinar datos de una consulta en pdo y mysqll

Tags: mysql, pdo

estoy realizando un pequeño trabajo pero me he quedado atascado ya que estoy haciendo una consulta con un inner join para 2 tablas pero me muestra la relacion separadas y quisiera que todos los resultados me los mostrara en la misma linea separadas por una coma (,) quien podria darme algun consejo?

```
$sql2 = "

      SELECT 

      rc_db.sku, rc_db.title, rc_db.length, rc_db.width, rc_db.height, rc_db.weight, rc_db.manufacturer, rc_db.category,

      rc_db_model.sku_m, rc_db_model.Model, rc_db_model.Make

      FROM rc_db_model INNER JOIN rc_db ON rc_db.sku=rc_db_model.sku_m WHERE Make != 'Jeep' limit 10



      ";
      $resp2=$cn->prepare($sql2);
      $resp2->execute();
      $products=$resp2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP);

       foreach ($products as $p => $value){

            echo "<h4>{$p}</h4>";

            foreach($value as $e => $data){


            $d =  $data['Make'].' '.$data['Model'].'>'.$data['category'];

            echo "<ul><li>$d</li></ul>";

            }              

            echo "<hr>";

          }
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xI1Yw.png">
```

Comment: Saludos. Te sugiero no uses el agruparlo por tag `ul` y el `li`; el resultado de `$d` lo agregues a un arrary y antes de `echo "<hr>";'  usar 'echo implode(',', $d);`; más sin embargo si debe ser con estos tag (es decir mediante CSS) te sugiero (este en inglés) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22729825/adding-after-li-except-for-last-li ve su estructura y allí mismo esta la solución.

Comment: es que fijate quiero juntar los 2 o mas valores dentro de un mismo input como podria hacerlo, usando el implode no me funciona porque si meto en un array la variable $d al ser 2 valores me los separa en arrays  diferentes y no los une: quiero unir los 2 en 1 solo campo ve como los muestra https://i.ibb.co/4W7Mgvd/input.png en html y en la consola: https://i.ibb.co/68WdTgx/console.png

Comment: Saludos. No funciona `$d=[];` y a continuación `foreach($value as $e => $data){


            $d[] =  $data['Make'].' '.$data['Model'].'>'.$data['category'];

            }` para que fuera del bucle `echo implode(', ', $d);`.? Según la documentación https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.implode.php (y las veces que lo use) debe juntar cada elemento de array para formar una sola cadena.

Comment: Si me ha funcionado lo que no entiendo es que me duplica los valores y me los coloca en los otros datos https://i.ibb.co/80FyDrh/console.png

Comment: Asi me esta mostrando los datos: https://i.ibb.co/wChNC1W/duplicate.png

Comment: Saludos de nuevo. El `$d` deber ser local al `foreach ($products as $p => $value)` (puede lo tengas desde fuera) de tal forma que cada vez que se repita dicho bucle se inicialice `$d=[];`.

Comment: Saludos amigo, muchisimas gracias, si no estaba declarando el $d antes del 2do foreach como array, muchas gracias amigo :D dejo foto de la solucion por si acaso https://i.ibb.co/30LJP2f/input.png <3 gracias de nuevo amigo